# Nodejs callbacks procedure

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

How the callbacks in nodejs works ?
In the below snippet, the 'hi' is transfered to another function.
Can anyone explain ?

```js
var y = (data,callback)=>{
    
    callback('hi');
}
var x = y;
x('data',(data)=>{
    console.log(data);    
});
```

Comment: What's your question exaclty?

Comment: It works exactly like any other function call. `foo(‘bar’)` passes the string `'bar'` to `foo`. The same happens with `callback` in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by setting the function pointer y to x

```
var x = y;
```

x becomes:

```
(data,callback)=>{

    callback('hi');
}
```

then x is called with 2 paramters 'data' and a fat arrow function :

```
x('data',(data)=>{
    console.log(data);    
});
```

the function is executed by:

callback('hi');

the string 'hi' becomes the parameter data of the given function